# In apache [authz_core:debug] [pid 21412] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 66.249.74.22:39835] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny

Tags: apache

I am getting this error message in **apache erro_log**

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 21412] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 66.249.74.22:39835] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 19):

this is no error it is a debug level message. It just says that the authorisation has ben granted for a request.

Your LogLevel variable in your apache or virtualhost configuration is set to debug. To fix this find in your config files

```
LogLevel debug
```

and change it to

```
LogLevel notice
```

If you want you can also use warn or error instead of notice. All possible levels are debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg

As you can see debug is the lowest setting and logs the most actions. For production environement you don't want that. You need it only if you are debugging a particular apache module or your apache configuration.

Comment: This does answer the question. There is no way to get rid of this message other than to turn down the LogLevel settings.

Comment: I'm a little confused. My LogLevel was set to warn and it's still pulling all those errors. Is there somewhere else that it might be causing it?

Comment: @cbloss793: Check for a stray "LogLevel debug" in your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` or other conf file, turns out that was overriding what was in the main apache.conf file for me.

Comment: Great tip! Thanks @LawrenceC!

Answer (score 4):

This answer is similar to Gregor's answer, which states that you need to reduce the verbosity of your logs.

But as of Apache 2.3.6, you have the ability to set a different `LogLevel` for each Apache module. So, in this case, you can keep the default `LogLevel` to `debug`, and just reduce the `LogLevel` of the `authz_core` module to `info` or anything else less verbose. To achieve that, in your configuration, change

```
LogLevel debug
```

to

```
LogLevel debug authz_core:info
```

This is the list of available log levels in order of verbosity: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel